# Tensorflow Object Detection API - What's actually test.record being used for?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have a few doubts about Tensorflow Object Detection API. Hopefully someone can help me out... Before that, I need to mention that I am following what [sendex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku&v=srPndLNMMpk) is doing. So basically, the steps are come from him.

**First doubt:** Why we need test.record for training? What it does during training?

**Second doubt:** Sendex is getting images from test.record to test the newly trained model, doesn't the model already knew that images because they are from test.record?

**Third doubt:** In what type of occasion we need to activate drop_out (in the .config file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It does nothing during training, you dont need that during training, but at certain time the model begins to [overfit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). It means the loss on training images continues to go down but the accuracy on testing images stops improving and begins to decline. This is the time when it is needed to stop traininga nd to recognise this moment you need the test.record.

2) Images were used only to evaluate model during training not to train the net.

3) You do not need to activate it, but using dropout you usually achieve higher accuracy. It prevents the net from overfitting.

Comment: thank you so much for replying and sharing your knowledge. I really appreciate it.

1) If so, may I know why in the model's config file, there's a section where we need to put the path of the train.record? 

2) How to recognize such moment by using test.record? I just hope that I can utilize test.record instead of just leaving it at there.

3) I need to achieve high accuracy. So I plan to turn on the dropout. Will the accuracy improve significantly?

Excuse me of being a totally novice in tensorflow and AI. Thanks

Comment: It is in eval_config section used for evaluation.  Run the command mentioned in documentation [https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md#running-the-evaluation-job]. Then run tensorboard command and look at the values of accuracy. Description of parameters used in config file can be found in protos directory.